# Function containing imaginary unit 'i' returns 'object i not found' error when used to fit

Tags: r, model-fitting

I am trying to fit some data with a real and an imaginary component. To do this, I have set up the following function:

```
fitfunc <- function(R1, C1, R2, C2, W1, W2, g)(R1 + (i*freq*C1 + 1/R2)^-1 + (i*freq*C2 + (W1(i*freq*W2)^-g)*tanh((i*freq*W2)^g)^-1)^-1)
```

When I try to use this function to fit my data using nls() with the line shown below:

```
fit <- nls(Z ~  fitfunc(R1, C1, R2, C2, W1, W2, g), data = Zfreq, start = list(R1 = 10, C1 = 1e-6, R2 = 10, C2 = 1e-6, W1 = 10, W2 = 10, g = 0.5))
```

I get an error message saying `'Error in fitfunc(R1, C1, R2, C2, W1, W2, g) : object 'i' not found`. How do I avoid this error? Any help would be really appreciated!:)

I'm quite new to r so am a bit stuck how to fit using functions with real and imaginary parts.

Comment: `i` by itself is not valid complex number syntax in R - it needs to be preceded by a numeric, e.g., `1i`. I'd suggest reading the `?complex` help page, especially the examples at the bottom.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I took a look and have added this in, thanks! I am now getting an error upon running the nls(): Error in qr.solve(QR.B, cc) : singular matrix 'a' in solve. Is this because my initial guesses for the parameters are bad?

Comment: Yes, that error *could* be because of bad starting conditions, but it's hard to say without more information.

Comment: There are also a whole bunch of error messages of the form: In storage.mode(lhs) <- "double" :
  imaginary parts discarded in coercion

Comment: What kind of information would be helpful? Thanks so much!